# Displaying 2 columns in UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

Is something like this possible? How?

Image made with some simple Photoshop.

[image: Some simple Photoshopping]

Comment: Not with the default UIActionSheet.  You maybe able to use the UIActivityViewController, though.  Take a look http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW121  You maybe able to access the CGRect frames of each button and change those but I am not sure whether that would make it through any app store review process

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the default `UIActionSheet`, However you can try custom control like
[TweetBot like UIAlertView and UIActionSheet replacement for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tweetbot-like-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own view controller with the desired view layout and animate the view when presenting. It's much easier than risking changing the default UIActionSheet look and feel.